# GitHub authentication error

Tags: git, github

I had been using GitHub for Mac for a while and it worked fine, but recently I had to reinstall it and now every time I try to clone a repo it just says "An authentication error occurred. We weren't able to clone the repository to your computer."

I also noticed that every time I restart the app my account info in settings disappears. Putting it back in doesn't fix the authentication error though.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened to me the same, the thing is it's not git fault, the Terminal is not working. It's working after a restart but i already lost all my repositories list trying all kind of things

Answer (score 0):

Force quit GitHub for mac and open again. Go to GiHub, go to your repo and "Clone to Desktop". Allow keychain permissions.